# Validating a one or more char string not starting and ending with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z '-]*[a-zA-Z]$/g
```

This regex  doesn't allow a string to end or begin with a space , `'` , `-` characters.

However, if I pass one string like `a` it will also be detected as invalid.

Please suggest how to pass one string but not space, `'`, `-`.

Thanks lot.

`a` -  correct 
 `a` - incorrect 
`'a` - incorrect

Comment: I think you need `/^[a-z](?:[a-z '-]*[a-z])?$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex requires an input that starts with a letter, then has 0+ chars like letters, space, single quote and hyphe, and then an obligatory letter. Wrap the last 2 parts of the pattern with an optional non-capturing group:

```
/^[a-z](?:[a-z '-]*[a-z])?$/i
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `i` case insensitive modifier will make the pattern a bit shorter.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `(?:[a-z '-]*[a-z])?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[a-z '-]*` - 0+ ASCII letters, spaces, `'` or `-`
  - `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `$` - end of string.